# Prove it is a geometric progression.

Tags: geometric-progressions

**Question**

Prove that if for an exponential function $ y = a^x (a>0;a \neq 1)$ the value of the argument $x=x_n(n=1,2,...)$ form an arithmetic progression, then the corresponding values of the function $y_n=a^{x_n}(n=1,2,...)$ form a geometric progression.

Comment: You've typed the question well.  Can you please edit in the work you've done so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know the following
$$ y = a^x $$
Now 
$$y_1 = a^{x_1}$$
$$y_2 = a^{x_2}$$
$$y_3 = a^{x_3}$$

$$\frac{y_3}{y_2} = \frac{a^{x_3}}{a^{x_2}}$$
$$\frac{a^{x_3}}{a^{x_2}} = a^{x_3-x_2}$$
$$a^{x_3-x_2} = a^{(A+2d)-(A+d)}$$
$$a^{(A+2d)-(A+d)} = a^d$$

Similarily

$$\frac{y_2}{y_1} = a^d$$

Hence we can show that 
$$ \frac{y^3}{y^2} = \frac{y_2}{y_1}$$

Therfore, we have proven that it is a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

Let an arithmetic sequence for exponents be $$ a, a+d, a+2d,....$$

The corresponding exponentials are $$ e^a ,e^{a+d}, e^{a+2d},....$$

$$e^a ,e^d e^a, e^{2d}e^a,....$$

$$e^a ,r e^a, r^2e^a,.......  $$

Which is a geometric sequence with r= e^d.